# Traditional Grip Finger Technique

Tags: drums, stick-control

Playing matched grip with mainly fingers is fairly straightforward, but I find that when playing traditional grip, I cannot achieve similar speeds using my fingers in traditional grip.

I have tried watching Dave Weckl's Back to Basics video. He suggests trying the fingers first in traditional grip with the palm facing down towards the drum head and dribbling. This feels great and easy, but as soon as I turn my hand over, I lose understanding of how my fingers are supposed to behave. Any advice or direction would be much appreciated!

Comment: Check out my answer there https://music.stackexchange.com/a/95078/63112 and in particular this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uWaFt4rz0zA

Answer (score 1):

When I'm playing with traditional grip, The stick barely rests on my ring finger on the upstroke, but still controlled by my middle finger. The stick lays on my ring finger above the top knuckle, next to the fingernail.

Here's a photo I found that shows a grip technique very similar to mine (on the left hand anyway - I don't know what's up with that right hand grip):
[image]

And here's a vide I've seen that explains the traditional grip technique pretty well: